# How can I change the white space between spans when adding them programmatically?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, nlp

Working on this [text alignment project](https://github.com/eelegiap/texthighlight) in D3.js, HTML/CSS, and Javascript. I am projecting all the words (actually tokens, including punctuation) in a text and its translation as spans. But the problem is that programmatically adding spans adds white space between them, and I need to be able to get rid of white space before punctuation. And yes, I have to add the spans programmatically because there are too many to write up in the HTML by hand. **How can I add a bunch of spans and change the white space between them?**

There is a `span` for the sentence and then a `span` with a `mark` for every token in the sentence. I add them like this (no CSS to note):

```
        data.tgtSentsInOrder.text.forEach(function (sent, i) {
            tgtdiv
                .append('span')
                .attr('id', 'tgtsent' + i)
                .attr('class', 'sentence chosen')

            var tokens = data.tgtSentsInOrder.tokens[i]

            tokens.forEach(function (t) {
                tgtcharcount += t.text.length
            })

            d3.select('#tgtsent' + i)
                .selectAll('span')
                .data(tokens)
                .enter()
                .append('span')
                .attr('id', function (d, j) { return ('tgtsent' + i + 'span' + j) })
                .attr('class', 'token')
                .append('mark')
                .attr('id', function (d, j) { return ('tgtsent' + i + 'token' + j) })
                .html(function (d, j) {
                    return d.text + ' '
                })
                .style('background-color', 'white')
        })
```

Any other design criticisms are welcome, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting your `<spans>` as `display: inline-block`? Usually this remove the white space generated by `inline` elements.

```
span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```